# Codeception. Actor classes loaded twice

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, codeception

I try to configure unit-tests suite in Codeception. When I run suite Codeception fail with error `Fatal error: Cannot re-declare class rest\tests\UnitTester`. With debugger I located places where it loads class first and second time.

First time Codeception load Actor in `Codeception\Test\Loader\Gherkin` during adding steps to loader.

Second time it initialize `Actor` instance for class with tests. In second place this class must be already included, but again loader is triggered. Here error appear.

Class is loaded with Codeception loader. At first I think that it was caused by namespace, but `UnitTester` is only one class in namespace. My `.yml` files a listed below. I would be very grateful for help.

codeception.yml:

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        Yii2:
            configFile: 'config/test-local.php'
```

unit.suite.yml:

```
class_name: UnitTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - Yii2
            - Asserts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason of this problem. My `codeception.yml` for this tests missing namespace param when classes in test folder was under namespace. This caused my problem.